# Get specific values from the object by its ID

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, search

Hi i have problem with angular getting a specific part of the object by id `( like an object but with specific id )` and really i don't know where to begin to solve it

```
   var Obj= [
            { Id: "1", shape: "circle", color: "red" },
            { Id: "2", shape: "square", color: "orange" },
            { Id: "3", shape: "triangle", color: "yellow" },
            { Id: "4", shape: "circle", color: "green" },
            { Id: "5", shape: "sphere", color: "blue" },
            { Id: "6", shape: "hexagon", color: "indigo" },
            { Id: "7", shape: "square", color: "violet" },
            { Id: "8", shape: "triangle", color: "red" }
        ];
```

for example the function must be like this

and  scope.result should be 
like :

```
 scope.result= [
 { Id: "3", shape: "triangle", color: "yellow" }
];
```

Comment: you mean something like a filter function ? `Obj.filter(function(x){return x.Id==3})`

Comment: filter and forEach are really nice to read and I use them myself, but you should be aware that if performance counts (with especially large datasets for example), you can't beat a for loop.  filter especially can be as much as 25 times slower.  JSPerf is down do to spam, otherwise I'd post the references here :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using angularJS:

```
$scope.result = [];
angular.forEach(Obj, function(value, key) {
    if (value.Id == "3"){
        $scope.result.push(value);
    }
});
alert(angular.toJson($scope.result));
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with a custom search function. In your case this function would be

```
function(e) { return e.Id == 3; }
```

[Example in a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xk09km5s/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an angular expert, but to find the item by an ID (or any other value), you should use the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function.

Here is an example:

```
function getItemById(id, stack) {
  // call the filter method 
  return stack.filter(function (item) {
    // return `true` if the item.Id matches
    return item.Id === id;
  // take the first of possible multiple matches
  // or `null` in case, there is no match
  })[0] || null;
}
```

You can use this function as followed:

```
var result = getItemById('3', stack);
```